# Javascript bootstrap datepicker not capturing data items on changeDate

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a table with a datepicker on each row:

```
<div id="[strand]" class="input-append dp date" data-origdate="[new_strand_appointmentdate]" data-date="[new_strand_appointmentdate]" data-stand="[strand]" >
    <input type="text" class="datemask" value="[new_strand_appointmentdate]" id="new_strand_appointmentdate[strand]" title="The appointment date" placeholder="__/__/____" name="strand_appointmentbydate">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

in my JS I capture the `changeDate` event:

```
$('.date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
```

I can see the dates in the console. What I can't get to are the data attributes I have set - the only one is the first record in the table even if that is not changed. `[strand]` is replaced with a unique number for each row, which I don't know in advance. How can I adjust my JS to pick up the data attributes so that I can work with them? I have tried:

```
var origdata = $('.date').data()
```

without getting anything useful.